# When is Procfile actually needed in Heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku, heroku-cli

I have installed Java, Git, Heroku CLI and have a Heroku account as well setup.

I have tried to follow this tutorial below:

[Java on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java)

And when I deploy the app it actually works just as expected. The thing is that I tried to
remove the *Procfile* since I read somewhere that its actually not needed and this time it
also worked well without that file.

But when I added my own Java maven project (non-web application) and pushed it to my Heroku app that I created on commandline I got a confirmation that my app is successfully deployed. 
But once I opened the app through **heroku open** command in a new browser I get this error:

[image: Error message]

So I run this **heroku logs --tail** command to check errors and at the end of the output I see
this:

> 2020-04-07T15:38:37.788790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"

So my guess is that I need to add a Procfile for the application so what I did was to create one in the root directory and add following line to it:

> web:java -jar target/mystuff-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

So it still didnt work. So I guessed I needed to scale up my application so ran
**heroku ps:scale web=1** but then I get the error message *Couldn't find that process type (web).*

Whats causing this thing to happen? Im getting a bit confused here

Any advice would be highly appreciated

Comment: Your Procfile is missing a space after the colon, that's why Heroku doesn't pick up your `web` process type. So it should be `web: java -jar target/mystuff-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. If this is not a fat-jar, make sure to add the required class path with `-cp` if needed.

Comment: I just corrected it according to your changes but I still get the same error display when I navigate to my app with "heroku open" command.

Comment: When I take a look at my logs I get the following output: 

2020-04-07T19:18:54.770776+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Comment: There should be some log output by your application before the one you pasted here. It should give more info about what's causing the H10 error code. Can you post it here?